# Need to recover files after mistakenly messing up the system but Ubuntu stuck at boot initramfs screen

Tags: boot, 22.04, data-recovery, initramfs, timeshift

I had been stuck with a package problem and was able to solve it after a long time. I decided to make a backup of the system settings before I proceeded. I installed Timeshift and set it up. It started making a backup but things went downhill from there. It ended up pushing my system storage to 0b from 80GB so I tried to remove the backup (/run/timeshift/backup).
In more detail, as soon as it popped up the "storage-low" error, I used the find "-iname timeshift" command to find where the backup was stored. I found it it '/run/timeshift/backup' and thought it was just the backup. I then used 'rm -rf' to delete the backup directory but immediately, the whole terminal closed, all the apps I had pinned vanished, and even the "Superkey" vanished. Only the Firefox app (which I had used to search for how to find the backup) was running. My consequent Google search told me that was more of a "shortcut" to the actual files than a backup.
That move removed all the apps in the system including Terminal and Settings. I am now unable to access my files or even the command line. Note that I am a new Linux user but am required to use it as part of my coursework. I need solutions (preferably recovery) since I don't want to lose my progress and get behind on coursework.

I have tried almost all online solutions that do not require a flash drive. No matter how I enter the boot, I end up in the "initramfs" screen as attached. I do not know how to proceed after this. I am also cautious since the system is not my device but belongs to my organization.
Please help!

[image: Initramfs page]

[image: System specifications]

---

**Edit 1:** I now know what I did was a stupid move. I welcome any suggestions to not have a repeat of this mishap. Considering that I am new to using Linux, any advice or backup recommendation would be appreciated. Thank you!

**Edit 2:** Have added more details about how I deleted the so-called backup

**Edit 3:** I made a LiveUSB as suggested, and plugged it into the USB port of the system. Then when I start the system, I am not even getting the initial setup screen (just getting a black screen). I tried with a senior's drive which she has already used as a bootable USB. Still no change. Now I am just getting a plain black screen even if I reboot without inserting the pen drive.

Comment: More detail about what "I tried to remove the backup" means would be helpful, since normally removing a backup would not destroy the system.

Comment: You NEED a flash drive. Borrow one. Create a LiveUSB. Use a friend's machine to make it. Boot into the "Try Ubuntu" environment. Look up how to use Photorec and/or Testdisk to recover your erased data. It may be very time-consuming (many hours!). Recover any data files onto a different media. Data only: Don't bother recovering system or application files. When you have exhausted data recovery, then use the installer to reinstall Ubuntu, then reinstall your applications, and finally restore your data recovered from that other media.

Comment: @user535733 Thank you. Is there no solution apart from reinstalling Ubuntu? Since it is an organization device, I would like to get things done as efficiently and quickly as possible without making it an issue.

Comment: From your description, you were thorough at self-inflicting this problem to be so hard to solve. Solving it yourself without ANY local assistance (like a LiveUSB) would be very challenging --and time-consuming-- for an expert. The key is determining whether your data was deleted or not. The easy, safe way to determine that is booting a LiveUSB's "Try Ubuntu" environment. If your data was not erased, then recovery is easy. If your data was erased, then you must Photorec/Testdisk to un-erase as much as you can find.

Comment: Since it is an organization device, they might be able to help you with recovery. They should certainly get the opportunity to reinstall their preferred OS onto their hardware.

Comment: Thank you so much @user535733! As soon as things poof-ed off in front of my eyes, I knew I had messed it up bad. Hopefully your solution restores things. I will look into Live USB tutorials and try my best. If I run into any more doubts, I might put it here for your (on anyone's) clarification before making any more mistakes :)

Comment: In many parts of the world, notifying your course instructors of your disaster is a very good idea. They can extend deadlines, offer advice, and help you reconstruct prior work.

Comment: Noted. Will let them know